# Tag merge: p2v and physical-to-virtual

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

The [p2v](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/p2v) and [physical-to-virtual](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/physical-to-virtual) tags are virtually (and physically!) the same thing and have both been used interchangeably. I propose merging them together into [p2v](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/p2v) would suffice.

Comment: I just asked the same question at the same time.

Comment: I noticed...now they need to merge the questions! ha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[physical-to-virtual](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/physical-to-virtual) has been merged into [p2v](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/p2v) as a synonym. Enjoy!